# Preserve spaces from attribute values with xpath

Tags: xpath, vbscript

Please consider this file: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml where line:

`<book category="children">`

is replaced with:

`<book category=" children ">`

Executing xpath query in vbscript for `category` attribute value:

```
For Each n In objXML.selectNodes("//book/@category")
    WScript.Echo n.text
Next
```

returns result where leading and trailing spaces are removed:

`children`

This doesn't happen with any other xpath evaluator I have tried.

So is it possible MS to return attribute value as it is, without removing spaces?

Comment: How do you know the spaces are removed? They are not distinguishable from the surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible through `value` property instead `text`. 
You'd like to know the differences between those two properties.
Please read the reference, especially **Remarks** sections.

[value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[text Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As you can see, in this case main differences between `value` and `text` is that **text** normalizes, **value** doesn't.

```
For Each n In objXML.selectNodes("//book/@category")
    WScript.Echo n.text
    WScript.Echo n.value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks again Kul-Tigin for your assistance